# Get each tr then the first two td

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri for a simple example to get council tax bands for a postcode (http://www.voa.gov.uk/cti/InitS.asp?lcn=0)

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
 a = Mechanize.new{ |agent|  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'}
 a.get('http://www.voa.gov.uk/cti/InitS.asp?lcn=0') do |page|
      form = page.form_with(:id => "frmInitSForm")
      form.txtPostCode = "NN15 6UA"
      page = a.submit form

      page.search("tr").each do |tr|
        textF = tr.text.strip
        textF.gsub!(/[\n]+/, "\n")
        puts textF

      end

    end
  end
```

At the moment this prints out all text inside the `tr`

I then need inside the `do` something similar to

```
tdFirst = tr.children("td:first").text
tdSecond = tr.children("td:nth-child(2)").text
```

How do I get the `first` and `second` td?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your inner block, try

```
tdFirst, tdSecond = tr.xpath('td')[0,2].map {|td| td.inner_text.strip}
puts "%s; %s" % [tdFirst, tdSecond]
```

Answer (score 2):

when using nokogiri, if you already got `tr`, then you can use

```
tds  = tr.xpath('td')
first = tds[0].text
second = tds[1].text
```

Answer (score 2):

Better than fetching all TDs and then paring it down you can use XPath like so:

```
td1, td2 = tr.xpath('td[1 or 2]').map(&:text).map(&:strip)
```

or CSS:

```
td1, td2 = tr.css('td:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(2)').map(&:text).map(&:strip)
```